# Push changes to bitbucket from server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to edit files on server with ftp and then use my source tree git client to push changes to bitbucket repository.

I've got a deploy key on server but its read only so I can use ssh to pull down changes but not push to bitbucket from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push something you must have a sufficient privileges to do so.
How do you want to push if you don't have credentials to do so?

If you can pull using ssh you should be able to push as well since SSH is a secures connection, it does not "care" if you read or write data (as long a you have the right permission on the machine regardless the ssh protocol.)

Comment: Im using deploy key and its read only on bitbucket. And the second part is that I want to use my local git client and edit code on server and push from server with local git client.

Comment: As far as i know (I'm working with sourcetree since the first release) its not possible even form command line. You will not be able to push if you have a read only key doesn't matter if you use GUI tool or CLI

Comment: Exactly. What do I need to do to give my server write access to bitbucket?

Comment: Depend on your system, you might need to generate pem fire for source tree or to deploy a new ssh key to you bitbucket account.